# cin loses first few characters of each line

Tags: c++, cin, cout

I've seen [other people](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/173682/) reporting this problem with `cin.ignore()` and `getline()`. I understand it's some problem involving newlines, but I'm not entirely sure how to debug this with >>. I'm trying to implement a gradebook that takes in a student name and test grades and outputs their name (and eventually, course grade) [from Chapter 4 of *Accelerated C++*]. I'm having trouble even outputting the names properly, though.

```
// Student.cpp
#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

istream& read(istream& in, Student& s) {
   in >> s.name >> s.midterm;
   read_hw(in, s.homework);
   return in;
}

istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw) {
    if (in) {
       hw.clear();

       double x;
       while (in >> x)
           hw.push_back(x);

       in.clear();
    }
    return in;
}
```

And here I try to test it with my main function:

```
int main() {
    vector<Student> students;
    Student curr_student;

    while (read(cin, curr_student)) {
        cout << curr_student.name;
        students.push_back(curr_student);
        cout << students.size() << endl;
    }

    cout << students.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        cout << students[i].name << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I input something into the command line, though, the output of the student names after the first one are cut off:

Input in terminal:

```
 Alice 50 50 50 50 (<enter>)
 Bob 100 100 100 100 (<enter>)
 Carl 50 50 50 50 (<enter>)
 (<Ctrl-D>)
```

And then it outputs:

```
 Alice
 ob
 rl
```

Comment: Take a look at answer 1 option 2: [Read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line). It will make your life much easier.

Comment: cin doesnt take space characters , you probably need to input stream reader function , you should probably write a loop for taking the rest of the mark values .

Comment: I am unable to [reproduce your problem.](http://ideone.com/jWoG74) However in order to make the attempt, I have had to move a few things around and fill in some blanks, so clearly the code I have run is not the same as yours. I recommend producing a [mcve] so we out here don't have to guess what we're doing differently from you.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of the result the grades are read using hex format: `B`, `C`, and `a` are vaild hex digits. That shouldn't be happen according to your cide, though.

In any case note that formatted reading will normally skip *all* leading white space, including newlines. There are a few approaches to deal with line ends. The usual one is to resd lines into a `std::string` and use the string to initialize an `std::istringstream`.

An alternative approach would be the use of a custom definition of line ends by specializing the `std::ctype<char>` facet to not consider newline a space character. Another approach is using a manipulator which consumes whitespace but sets `std::ios_base::failbit` upon encountering a newline. For example:

```
std::istream& skip(std::istream& in) {
    if (std::istream::sentry kerberos{in, true}) {
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(in), end;
        if (end != (it = std::find_if(it, end, [](unsigned char c){
                return !std::isspace(c) || char(c) == '\n'; }))
            && *it == '\n') {
            ++it;
            in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
         }
    }
    return in;
}
// ...
if (in) {
    while (in >> skip >> x) {
        hw.push_back(x);
    }
    if (!hw.empty()) {
        in.clear();
    }
}
```

While I don't think I'd be able that the original code actually reproduces the problem I'm fairly sure that the above approach does fix it!